# Strategy for login statistics T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a large website with hundred of thousands of users. We store login information in a table with one row for each login. This table are archived after a couple of months.

We want to show login statistics on this table for OrganisationUnits in an organisation. A user can be part of several organisationUnits.

Example Query:

```
 SELECT o.name,
     (select count(l.loginID) 
      from logins AS l 
        LEFT JOIN organisationUnitParticipants AS op 
          ON l.userID = op.userID 
      WHERE op.organisationUnitID = o.organisationUnitID 
        AND (logintime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)) AS loginCount
 FROM organisationUnits AS o
 WHERE o.organisationID = @organisationID
```

This Query takes about 14 second to run if I set the date to a month interval. Indexes exists and no table scan occurs.

Reason why it takes so long is just the massive amount of data in logins table.

I'm looking for a better way of storing the data or a better SQL script at least.

users can jump in and out of organisationUnits. No need to keep history of that we just want the count at where they are today.

Comment: What indexes, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select o.name, count(l.loginID) 
from logins AS l 
   left join organisationUnitParticipants op 
       on op.userID = l.userID 
   join organisationUnits o 
       on o.organisationUnitID = op.organisationUnitID 
where o.organisationID = @organisationID
   and logintime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
group by o.name
```